# problems with cron in nginx docker container

Tags: docker, cron

From a base image of nginx, I installed certbot, successfully got the certs and website works fine over ssl, so now I want to put the renew script as a cron job, but it doesnt seem to be working, I just wanted to check it was working with echo Helloworld:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world!" >> /root/cron2.log 2>&1
```

But nothing shows up in /root, also, there are no logs present in the usual dirs like /var/log/, and there is no file syslog except for /usr/include, and no rsyslog,

What am I doing wrong with CRON? so that I can assess my dry-run renew script in a log so I know its working?

Comment: try starting the cron service by using `service cron start` to check manually and then add the same to init-script/ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Must of been a long day, that was the thing I was missing, with it installing the new cron tabs ok from crontab -e, I guess I just presumed it was running, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to make sure that the service is actually run, with:

```
service cron start
```